# adb acting up when connecting to devices using a script

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb, xargs

I'm trying to automate some things and get adb to connect to a list of devices. I'm using curl to retrieve a list of IP's but for the sake of simplicity I'm just using a simple file right now with the content being:

```
192.168.1.108
192.168.1.54
```

I have tried to execute

```
cat devices | xargs -L1 -t ./adb connect
```

which results in

```
/adb connect 192.168.1.108
:5555cted to 192.168.1.108
/adb connect 192.168.1.54
:5555cted to 192.168.1.54
```

and adb devices yields

```
List of devices attached
:555568.device
:555568.unauthorized
```

Which does not make any sense to me.
If I manually enters the connect-commands, adb devices says

```
List of devices attached
192.168.1.108:5555      offline
192.168.1.54:5555       offline
:555568.device
:555568.unauthorized
```

which is more like what I would have expected (except for the two weird devices). To me it seems like the input (commands) are the same but the output is different but what causes the difference?
I have also tried a simple "while read line do ... end" script which results in the same weird behavior.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you have the `-t` flag for `xargs`? It prints the command line on the standard error output before executing it. Can you remove it and try?

Comment: It has been some time since I've been using xargs and shell scripting so I just added it to check what was being executed. I have tried with and without and it makes not difference (except for the commands being shown of course).

Comment: Did you check for any CRLF file endings (DOS style line endings) on the file your received from output of `curl`? May be try running `dos2unix devices` on the file before running the adb commands

Comment: Wow, that actually solved the problem! Did not except it be so simple, especially when the verbose output of xargs seemed to be fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is most likely due to the presence of CRLF line terminators coming in from copy pasting text from a Windows machine. You can check that by doing

```
file devices 
devices: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

You need to convert CRLF to LF, to do so you can run this command.

```
dos2unix devices
```